# Blocked Error when running a .jar file in Linux Mint

Tags: java, jar, runtime, blocked

With Eclipse on Linux Mint, I made a .jar file from a Java project containing a simple GUI. In the Terminal, this .jar file runs correctly, but when I try to run it with rightclick →Open with → Open JDK Java 11 Runtime, I get a window with the following error:
“The file ‘this_is_the_file_name’.jar is not marked as executable. If this was downloaded or copied from an untrusted source, it may be dangerous to run. For more detailes read about the executable bit.”.
Note: Another .jar file downloaded from the Internet runs with  rightclick →Open with → Open JDK Java 11 Runtime.
Please, tell me how must I create the .jar file in order to run with rightclick →Open with → Open JDK Java 11 Runtime.
Thank you very much!

Comment: It's not "blocked".  On Linux (unlike DOS/Windows), executable files and scripts ... require "execution" permissions..  ANYWAY: look here for several different options for running a .jar on Linux: https://askubuntu.com/questions/192914/how-run-a-jar-file-with-a-double-click

Comment: "Blocked" isn't OP's terminology, it's what the dialog says. Pointing out that executables need execution permissions doesn't help OP, and neither does your link.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your good answers. With rightclick on the .jar file -> Properties, in 'Permission' tab tick "Allow executing file as program" solves that error.
In order to run the file with doubleclick: rightclick ->Properties in 'Open with'tab select Open JDK Java 11 Runtime.
That .jar file I downloaded from the Internet has default ticked "Allow executed file as program". I ask how was this made by programming (this is useful when I give my file to be used by other person).
Good coding to all!